# Svelte internals: how does reactive declaration syntax work

Tags: svelte

Regarding reactive declarations in svelte like 
`$: doubled = count*2`, it states in the [svelte tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/reactive-declarations) that

> Don't worry if this looks a little alien. It's valid (if unconventional) JavaScript, which Svelte interprets to mean 're-run this code whenever any of the referenced values change'

The conventional javascript feature refrences seems to be [labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) (please confirm)

Please explain how this is done by the svelte compiler in simple words and provide a reference to the place in the compiler code where this happens [or starts to happen]

There is a [githb issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/2464) open to explain svelte internals eventually.

Comment: Try making a simple example in the https://svelte.dev/repl and inspect the JS output on the right hand side.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is indeed the label syntax.

Javascript labels are seeing little to no use, so it was an elegant way to make create a simple syntax as well making sure it would play nice with linters and IDEs.

**Where can you find the code :**

Once the code is compiled, you can find the reactive declarations in the **state update** part of the component lifecycle. However this code is not executed between the beforeUpdate and afterUpdate which are related to the **DOM update**. If you change values in those callbacks, you might get some wacky results as the reactive statements may not be updated.

You can find it in the code if you look for `$$self.$$.update`.

**How it works :**

The compiler is analyzing those statements to find which variables to observe for changes. Those variables being everything right of the assignment operator, or every argument in a function call. It is worth noting that const variables are not observed as they are never supposed to change.

`$: doubled = count * 2;`

will compile to

`if ($$dirty.count) { $$invalidate('doubled', doubled = count * 2); }`

$$dirty is the argument received by the update lifecycle, it is an object containing properties for each variables potentially modified, that are set to 1 when `$$invalidate` is called on it.

Svelte then add thoses statements at the end of the update part of the lifecycle, and condition their execution on the changes of at least one of the aforementioned observed variables.

Svelte is also ordering those statements in a topological order. This means that a reactive statement making use of another reactive statement results is going to be evaluated after. Regardless in which order you put them in your code.

```
$: quadrupled = doubled * 2;
$: doubled = count * 2;
```

will still correctly compile to

```
if ($$dirty.count) { $$invalidate('doubled', doubled = count * 2); }
if ($$dirty.doubled) { $$invalidate('quadrupled', quadrupled = doubled * 2); }
```

Hope it helps clear things up.